# Installing Ubuntu Alone, Along Side & Along Side in a Separate Partition

Tags: grub2

I have several times installed, Uninstalled Ubuntu during last 2 years
I would like to know which file/folder is controlling the grub screen even if i delete the ext4 / partition in following case.

1. Installed Ubuntu Alone in a fresh disk in BIOS mode.
2. Installed Ubuntu Alone in a fresh disk in UEFI mode.
3. Installed Ubuntu along side Windows in BIOS mode.
4. Installed Ubuntu along side Windows in UEFI mode.

in above cases if i delete the ext 4 / partitions, i still be able to see GRUB screen..how can i delete the file/folder which is controlling this GRUB screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` controls the grub screen.  Also keep in mind that deleting a partition does not modify the filesystem on that partition.  So all files and data will remain intact until you overwrite them with other data (eg. by creating a partition there again and creating a new filesystem).

But I think the real question you're asking is how to uninstall grub as the bootloader.  For cases 1 and 2, uninstalling grub doesn't matter as it will get overwritten when you install the next OS.  For cases 3 and 4 you'll need to [reinstall the Windows bootloader](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/).

Comment: /boot/grub/grub.cfg lies in ext4 partition which is mounted to / (back slah). when i delete or format ext4 partition, i can still be able to see grub..how is it possible?

Comment: @PRATAP Grub writes the boot code to the MBR (master boot record) on the disk - the first 512 bytes or so. You will have to removed the MBR to get rid of the grub messages, or install an other boot loader.

Comment: @Soren A Hi, thanks for responding. means Installing Ubuntu in BIOS mode and UEFI mode will have two different ways to control GRUB am i rite?

Comment: @PRATAP from your perspective, controlling grub in a UEFI vs BIOS install will be essentially the same (edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`).  There are some fairly big technical differences between the two.  @soren-a's comment refers to BIOS mode.  In UEFI the UEFI BIOS looks for an EFI_SYSTEM partition which is structured a certain way and that's where the main boot code of grub will live.  But in either case the booted grub looks for `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for setting up the screen.

Comment: @crass my main aim is how to delete the grub controller after deleting Ubuntu partition from the disk. The above file you are all mentioning is /boot/grub/grub.cfg I have deleted ext4 / partition in all 4 cases but still be able to see grub controller. When I delete ext4 / partition from my system /boot/grub/grub.is no more in my system but still I see grub why?

Comment: @PRATAP grub has an [embedded config file](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Embedded-configuration.html) which is what you're seeing. For the BIOS case you'll need to wipe out the grub code installed in unused space in the filesystem what was specified when installing grub (you can just zero out the first several megabytes of the partition).  For the UEFI case you should be able to just delete the grub UEFI app (in the EFI_SYSTEM partition at `/efi/boot/boot*.efi` in a normal setup).

Answer (score 1):

> I have several times installed, Uninstalled Ubuntu during last 2 years
>   I would like to know which file/folder is controlling the grub screen
>   even if i delete the ext4 / partition in following case.
>
> 1. Installed Ubuntu Alone in a fresh disk in BIOS mode.

If you boot into the installed system, you will find the configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This is in the root partition in the standard case, but if you created a `boot` partition (and not only a `/boot` directory in the root partition's file system), that is where you find it. You can use `df` to identify the block device,

```
df /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If you create a system with LVM and encryption via the Ubuntu installer, there will be a `boot` partition.

If you delete the root partition and that is where the grub configuration file is located, it will also be deleted.

> 2. Installed Ubuntu Alone in a fresh disk in UEFI mode.

The same as 1.

> 3. Installed Ubuntu along side Windows in BIOS mode.

The same as 1.

> 4. Installed Ubuntu along side Windows in UEFI mode.

The same as 1.

> in above cases if i delete the ext 4 / partitions, i still be able to
>   see GRUB screen..how can i delete the file/folder which is controlling
>   this GRUB screen?

---

But if there are several Ubuntu and other Linux installed systems, it is usually the last one that you installed, that is controlling the configuration of the grub menu. So boot into that system, and run

```
df /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

in order to find in which partition/file system, that the active configuration file is located.

If you cannot boot into Ubuntu or another Linux installed system because you have already deleted all root partitions, boot live from a USB/DVD drive, look for `boot` partitions, which are usually rather small and usually have the `ext4` file system.

If you remove the active `boot` partition or the grub files from it, and Windows depends on `grub` for booting, there will be problems, so it is a good idea to keep it, or at least make a full backup of the drive before you start tampering with it.

It is possible to reinstall the Windows bootloader, but as long as you can boot Windows via `grub`, you need not do it.